# Generate ClickMouseButton(0) anywhere on display

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

Here is my script:

```
void Update () {
    public float clickTimer = 2f;
    clickTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
    if(clickTimer <= 0){
        //"Generate Click" I try: Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0);
        clickTimer = 2f;
    }
}
```

I don't want to click any specific object because I have RayCastHit and I want to generate click anywhere on display.

Comment: Instead of "generating a click" you probably just want to mimic whatever code that a normal mouseclick would do. So if your real mouse click creates a ray, you click generator should also just generate a ray.

Comment: what you need the click random or raycastRandom? or the click in the rayCastHit screen position?

Comment: @joreldraw http://prntscr.com/gko2s6 http://prntscr.com/gko5rg  This is actualy my code. I just want to Unity generate LeftClickDown anywhere on display because is not matter where is clicked in Cardboard aplication it always generate Ray in the middle of the screen.

Comment: try gameObject.SendMessage("OnMouseDown");

Comment: "SendMessage OnMouseDown has no receiver!" I think SendMessage just call function OnMouseDown, but i dont have that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this script (which is for 2D games) you can create a RayCast from the point in the screen where you clicked with the mouse, and check what GameObjects you have hit. I recommend you to tag first any GameObject you want to be clicked

```
void Update () {

    clickTimer -= Time.deltaTime;

    if(clickTimer <= 0){

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {

            //What point was pressed
            Vector3 worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint( Input.mousePosition );
            worldPoint.z = Camera.main.transform.position.z;
            //Generate a Ray from the position you clicked in the screen
            Ray ray = new Ray( worldPoint, new Vector3( 0, 0, 1 ) );
            //Cast the ray to hit elements in your scene
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.GetRayIntersection( ray );

            if(hit.collider != null) {
                 Debug.Log("I hit: "+hit.gameObject.tag);
                //And here you can check what GameObject was hit

                if(hit.gameObject.tag == "AnyTag"){
                     //Here you can do whatever you need for AnyTag objects
                }
            }
        }   

        clickTimer = 2f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While this is generally bad practice (you should design the system in a way such that there's just a function you call upon mouse click and then you can call that function anywhere so you don't need to simulate one) it is possible to simulate a mouse click at a certain position in [C# .net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/).

The first step is to move the mouse cursor to the desired position (I know you don't want to do this, you can set to some of the later steps to just generate a mouse click, this is just for future reference), Unity doesn't natively have any way to control the mouse cursor. This means that the example I'm going to show here will only work on windows machines, you'll have to implement different code to get it to work on OSX. First we must start by including:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

in our script, this line is what will allow us to import the user32.dll so that we can re-position the mouse to where we want. So then the next stage is to import the function that will allow us to move the mouse, this is done like so

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);
```

We can now use this function in our code to set the position of the mouse cursor, now remember the `user32.dll` is windows only and thus it's not portable to other Operating Systems. This is the major reason why you should avoid doing it this way.

```
public void Start()
{
    SetCursorPos(50, 50);
}
```

On windows Operating Systems `0,0` is the top left point of the screen, the co-ordinates don't scale to the screen size so if you want to get the center of the screen for every  resolution you would have to get the display size using the [Screen](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.html) class.

After positioning the mouse correctly all we need to do is perform a mouse click, unfortunately this is quite tricky and .net doesn't really have any built in ways to do this. The best choice at this point is this class that can perform mouse operations for us:

```
public class MouseOperations
{
    [Flags]
    public enum MouseEventFlags
    {
        LeftDown = 0x00000002,
        LeftUp = 0x00000004,
        MiddleDown = 0x00000020,
        MiddleUp = 0x00000040,
        Move = 0x00000001,
        Absolute = 0x00008000,
        RightDown = 0x00000008,
        RightUp = 0x00000010
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetCursorPos")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);      

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetCursorPos(out MousePoint lpMousePoint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

    public static void SetCursorPosition(int X, int Y) 
    {
        SetCursorPos(X, Y);
    }

    public static void SetCursorPosition(MousePoint point)
    {
        SetCursorPos(point.X, point.Y);
    }

    public static MousePoint GetCursorPosition()
    {
        MousePoint currentMousePoint;
        var gotPoint = GetCursorPos(out currentMousePoint);
        if (!gotPoint) { currentMousePoint = new MousePoint(0, 0); }
        return currentMousePoint;
    }

    public static void MouseEvent(MouseEventFlags value)
    {
        MousePoint position = GetCursorPosition();

        mouse_event
            ((int)value,
            position.X,
             position.Y,
             0,
             0)
             ;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MousePoint
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public MousePoint(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }

    }

}
```

After adding that into the project we can then use this class to simulate mouse operations, this can be done like so:

```
MouseOperations.MouseEvent(MouseOperations.MouseEventFlags.LeftDown | MouseOperations.MouseEventFlags.LeftUp);
```

That line there will perform a left click, the mouse event function takes in pre-made flags that can perform different mouse functions. If you only passed the LeftDown flag then it would keep the left mouse button down performing a left click hold. That's why you must also pass the left up flag to get a click.

[Here's the code I used that worked flawlessly on my test project.](https://pastebin.com/aFYaWqKP)

Just to stress this point again, you shouldn't be doing it this way. This is a clunky and unreliable hack. The proper and good way to do it would be to have the normal left click simply call a function, and whenever you wanted that left click to occur you could call the function instead of having to go through the convoluted steps to simulate one.